# Проблемы с запуском Python программы в консоли

Tags: python

Написал небольшую тест-программу для вывода уведомлений на Windiws 10. В программе (у меня VS Code) Все работает прекрасно, но как только запуская программу через значок, то просто появляется и тут же пропадает окно консоли. Я попытался открыть консоль и указать путь до файла, но пишет, что нет необходимого модуля plyer, хотя он установлен (кстати точно также с модулем Colorama)

Вот сам код, ошибок нет:

```
    from plyer import notification
    def notif(valueTitle, valueMessage):
    notification.notify(
    title = valueTitle,
    message = valueMessage,
    timeout = 10
    )


a = str( input('Введите заголовок: ') );
b = str( input('Введите текст уведомелния: ') );

notif(a, b);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я сделал тоже самое через IDLE Python 3.7.3 и... код запустился, но уведомлений нет. Попробуйте перенести файлы plyer в папку к исполняемому файлу

Comment: Установлен как локальный (в виртуальном окружении) или как глобальный?

Comment: win7 python 3.6 все работает

Comment: @Стас. Переместил, не получилось

Comment: @Дмитрий, извините, но я даже не знаю, что такое виртуальное окружение(

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1116621/234134

Comment: @D.Violet, уже решил проблему минут 30-40 назад, но все равно спасибо